# Slide rearrange issue in PPT

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-pptx

I have a script thatopens the ppt file and displays all the slide name with index in the list box. the user can move up and down the title in list box. after rearanging the slides the slides in the ppt file should re arange as per the new order.

I see the slides are rearranging but its re arranging in random order not in the given order. This is my code:

```
 **CODE**


def apply_new_order():
        
        new_slide_pos = []
        
        # xml_slides = presentation.slides
        xml_slides = presentation.slides._sldIdLst
        slides = list(xml_slides)
        # reorderd_slides = [slide_title_to_slide[slide_titles] for slide_title in new]
        original_slide_index = [idx for idx, _ in enumerate(slides)]
        print("this is Originalindex", f"{original_slide_index}")
        
        new_slide_indices = list_box.get(0,tk.END)
        print("this is new slide indices, "f"{new_slide_indices}")
        for index in new_slide_indices:
            slide_new_index  = index.split('.')
            print("this is new slde indices after spliting"f"{slide_new_index}")
            new_slide_pos.append(slide_new_index[0])
            new_slide_pos_str = ','.join(new_slide_pos)
        print("This is new slide indices after join ,"f"{new_slide_pos_str}")    
        new_order_list =list(map(int,new_slide_pos_str.split(',') ))
        
        
        # slide_to_reorder = [slides.pop(original_index) for original_index in sorted ( original_slide_index, reverse = True)]
        slide_to_reorder = [slides[original_index] for original_index in original_slide_index]
        # for slide_to_move, new_order in zip(reversed(slide_to_reorder), reversed (new_order_list)):
        # for slide_to_move, new_order in zip(slide_to_reorder,  new_order_list):
        for new_position, slide_to_move in enumerate (slides):
            new_order = new_order_list[new_position] - 1 
            xml_slides = presentation.slides._sldIdLst
            xml_slides.remove(slides[new_position])
            xml_slides.insert(new_order,slides[new_position])
         
        presentation.save(mergedPPT)
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76809889/edit) your question and format your code [guide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Further, we need all your code. For example I don't even see where python-pptx comes into it.